# How to filter the div as we search in search box?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I made a page with 9 cards. The card is with the class name "card". I want to get the card when I type the letters. I want this to be filtered on the basis of p tag that consist "First project", "Second project" and so on for seven more.

```js
function search() {
  let input = document.getElementById('.searchbar').value
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let x = document.querySelector('.card p');

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "list-item";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <h3 class="first">Page Heading <span class="span-text">Secondary Text</span></h3>
  <form class='searchbox'>
    <input class="searchbar" type="text" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  </form>

  <section class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-box">700 x 400</div>
      <p style="color:blue; font-size:1.5rem;">First Project</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quod non sed eveniet numquam perferendis.
      </p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-box">700 x 400</div>
      <p style="color:blue; font-size:1.5rem;">Second Project</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quod non sed eveniet numquam perferendis.
      </p>
    </div>
    //and seven more of same "card" class
</div>
```

I am not able to filter it when I type in the search box. Kindly guide on what is wrong and what I can do  to display the card that I searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line,

```
let input = document.getElementById('.searchbar').value
```

To,

```
let input = document.querySelector('.searchbar').value
```

-> Because using `getElementById` you can select the element with particular id but here you are using class and you cannot do like this..

> But anyhow it is always the best practice to make function call in the
>   javascript file with the help of [**addEventListener()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) and remove `onkeyup="search()"` in HTML template

-> Consider using `nth` selection option to select the first p element which is second element from `card` div like `('.card p:nth-child(2)')`,

```
const x = document.querySelectorAll('.card p:nth-child(2)');
```

Note that here you need to use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements with the selection and this will return array of elements..

Working **Snippet** as follows,

```js
const searchEl = document.querySelector('.searchbox');
const x = document.querySelectorAll('.card p:nth-child(2)');

function search(e){
  x.forEach((item,index) => {
    if(!item.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value)){
      item.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }else {
      item.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
    }
  })
}

searchEl.addEventListener("keyup", search);
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <h3 class="first">Page Heading <span class="span-text">Secondary Text</span></h3>
  <form class='searchbox'>
    <input class="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  </form>

  <section class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-box">700 x 400</div>
      <p style="color:blue; font-size:1.5rem;">First Project</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quod non sed eveniet numquam perferendis.
      </p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-box">700 x 400</div>
      <p style="color:blue; font-size:1.5rem;">Second Project</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quod non sed eveniet numquam perferendis.
      </p>
    </div>
    //and seven more of same "card" class
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. One thing I didn't understand is although the p tag with "First project" is the first child of the card class, you wrote n:thchild(2). Why is it here 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @ShirishPokhrel, Sorry for not explaining it clearly.. Edited the answer.. We are using querySelector on ```.card``` which is parent element inside that we are selecting the p element which is the second element from the ```card``` div.. If you want the description ```p``` tag then you can use ```'.card p:nth-child(3)'```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Learned something today.

Answer (score 1):

```
function search() {
   // Get input value
   const input = document.querySelector('.searchbox > .searchbar').value.toLowerCase();
   // Get all cards in page
   const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.cards > .card');
   cards.forEach(card => {
      // Get card title
      const title = card.querySelector('p').innerText.toLowerCase();
      // Hide card if card title does not match
      card.style.display = title.includes(input) ? null : 'none';
   });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't filters yet. I think there should be something else instead of null.

Answer (score 1):

Changed your `getElementById()` to `querySelector()` since you used css class selector to select searchbox.

Changed your `querySelector()` to `querySelectorAll()` since you want to select multiple card p elements.

Changed the `search()` function name to `filter()` since it was conflicting with the name attribute of the searchbox which was also `search`. Alternatively you can bind the event handler in JavaScript. Declaring event handlers inline is considered bad practice by many developers.

Last I changed the search logic so it filters the cards based on the title alone since you had 2 p elements in each card. Also hidden the card element instead of the p elements. I added the title class the the title `p` to use it as a selector.

```js
function filter() {
  let input = document.querySelector('.searchbar').value //<-- Changed to querySelector
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card'); //<-- Changed to querySelectorAll with '.card' selector.

  //loop over cards and compare search with title.
  cards.forEach((el) => {
    let title = el.querySelector('.title').textContent.toLowerCase();
    el.style.display = title.includes(input) ? "list-item" : "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <h3 class="first">Page Heading <span class="span-text">Secondary Text</span></h3>
  <form class='searchbox'>
    <input class="searchbar" type="text" onkeyup="filter()" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  </form>

  <section class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-box">700 x 400</div>
      <p class="title" style="color:blue; font-size:1.5rem;">First Project</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quod non sed eveniet numquam perferendis.
      </p>
    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-box">700 x 400</div>
      <p class="title" style="color:blue; font-size:1.5rem;">Second Project</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quod non sed eveniet numquam perferendis.
      </p>
    </div>
    //and seven more of same "card" class
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my old projects. I used  insted of card, but I get it that you are tring to do the same process which I did.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }

    var uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
    for (var j = 0; j < uls.length; j++) {
        var ul = uls.item(j);
        for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="myUL">

    <li><a href="sampleprofile.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Chain_link_icon.png" style="float: right; box-shadow: none" ;>Nargesh Rana
            <p>Some Text Here is Nice</p>
            <p>New Delhi 110057</p>
        </a></li>

    <li><a href="sampleprofile.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Chain_link_icon.png" style="float: right; box-shadow: none" ;>Rajesh Kumar
            <p>Some Text Here is Nice</p>
            <p>New Delhi 110019</p>
        </a></li>

    <li><a href="sampleprofile.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Chain_link_icon.png" style="float: right; box-shadow: none" ;>Nargesh Rana
            <p>Some Text Here is Nice</p>
            <p>New Delhi 110047</p>
        </a></li>

    <li><a href="sampleprofile.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Chain_link_icon.png" style="float: right; box-shadow: none" ;>Nargesh Rana
            <p>Some Text Here is Nice</p>
            <p>New Delhi 110047</p>
        </a></li>

    <li><a href="sampleprofile.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Chain_link_icon.png" style="float: right; box-shadow: none" ;>Nargesh Rana
            <p>Some Text Here is Nice</p>
            <p>New Delhi 110047</p>
        </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is on line 2

```
let input = document.getElementById('.searchbar').value;
```

debugging it should give you:

```
let input = document.getElementsByClassName('searchbar').value;
```

Also on line 4, change:

```
let x = document.querySelector('.card p');
```

to:

```
let x = document.querySelectorAll('.card p');
```